# STRING EXTRACTION/TRUNCATE from a given character in java

Tags: java

Hi i am doing a UI PROJECT in java. i would like to truncate a string or sequence of character from a given  string for example:
 if 000101 is the user input
the output of the string will be 101.
P.S: the occurrence of 0's before 1 may be anything.

please help me!!

Comment: You may be doing your brain a disservice by not allowing it to try to write the code first itself, and you may be giving it an insult by not thinking that it is capable of doing so. I'm betting that it is. I say, give it a go first, and see what you come up with -- you may be pleasantly surprised. Also, then if you're still not successful, you can post a **much** better and more informative question, one that shows us your code and your precise thoughts on your problem, and one that likely would allow us to give much more specific and helpful suggestions.

Comment: yes, please provide some code ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, and I encourage you to figure out a way on your own.

Here's one answer to this question:

Why not try to take the user input and keep cutting off the first character of the string until you reach a nonzero number?

For example, let's say you have a string called "userInput".

```
while(userInput.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
    userInput = userInput.substring(1);
```